# Display video st

Tags: video, camera, stream

I have two cameras setup in my house. What are possible ways to display their stream on a web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically the cameras contain miniature webservers that can serve up the video in a format that can be shown in the browser.

Look at [Axis](http://www.axis.com/) products.